# Запуск Python и при запуске Chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, flask

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске `Google Chrome` запускался мой питон файл с `flask`?

localhost при запуске хрома уже настроил. Теперь нужно сделать так, чтобы запускался Python файл...

Пытался искать в гугле но не смог ничего найти полезного. Находил только вопросы по теме `webbrowser.open(...)`.

Буду предельно благодарен за любую ссылку и ответ!

Comment: Отслеживать в процессах процесс гугл-хрома и запускать свой файл питона

Comment: Это я понимаю, но как это организовать... никаких мыслей. За этим сюда и написал

Comment: Так что, @gil9red, буду благодарен за любое решение

Comment: Используйте `psutil` чтобы найти процесс, пример поиска https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c9b4b382194a9a28a755751a393efb1dcb9ccc5a/psutil_example/loop_kill_process_by_name.py#L14 . После проверьте, что по ip/порту который займет ваш сервер на фласке никого нет (будем считать, что там может быть только ваш сервер) сделав запрос по адресу через requests, после запускайте файл с сервером через subprocess: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/811b070492e4b3ead4e878ffb737e5a005a2353f/webserver__handler_key_mouse_click_and_move/main.py#L37

Comment: Мне кажется это оверинженеринг, почему всегда не быть запущенным  flask или при запуске flask запускать браузер?